# Input Iterator for a shared_ptr

Tags: c++

I have an iterator which contains the following functions:

```
    ...
    T &operator*() { return *_i; }
    std::shared_ptr<T> operator->() { return _i; }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> _i;
    ...
```

How do I get a shared pointer to the internally stored _i?

```
std::shared_ptr<Type> item = ???
```

Should I do:

```
MyInterfaceIterator<Type> i;
std::shared_ptr<Type> item = i.operator->();
```

Or should I rewrite operator*()?

Comment: What type is i variable in your last example?

Comment: @Denis Ermolin  Updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can edit the code you can add a simple `get` function that return the internal `shared_ptr`!! It's better than calling `operator->` directly, isn't it??

Answer (score 1):

In terms of iterators you have to write  `operator*()` to dereference it. Actually it's your iterator and you can write anything you want. But since C++ programmers use `std` widely, better if you will use `operator*()` because its more clear for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `std` is getting the object by dereferencing the iterator, I'd say:

```
std::shared_ptr<T> operator*() { return _i; }
```

Also, note that if you're just trying to call methods on `T`, you don't need to get the pointer first, because `operator->()` is chaining. That means that

```
it->foo();
```

will call `T::foo()` even though `it.operator->()` returns a shared poitner.

Comment: Can you fix the first line in your answer please. It looks like some text is missing there.

Comment: @Baz I don't see any text missing. What did you have in mind?

Comment: What do you mean by "the std"?

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution?

```
std::shared_ptr<T> operator()(){...}
```

Comment: Hm you answered on this question like you are another person)

Comment: @Luksprog This is a complete answer. Whether its a good one or not is another question... :)

Comment: It may be an answer but it doesn't look like one(answering with a question isn't an answer). Also if you ask in your question *Should I do:...or ...* you could have included this answer in the question as one of the alternatives.